# Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection

Tags: centos, networking

I added a new connection config (CentOS 7):

```
DEVICE="eth1"
BOOTPROTO="static"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR=10.68.0.1
GATEWAY=10.68.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
```

Next, I ran `systemctl restart network` and got an error in `journalctl`:

```
Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CentOS 7 uses "predictable interface names", a new convention for naming network devices that replaces the old `eth*` convention. Thus, your device is named something else, probably something like `enp0s25`, not `eth1`. Check with `ip a` what your device is named, and substitute it for `eth1` in your config file.